# $\omega$-limit set of a point $x \in X$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, definition

I would like to verify whether the following definition of the $\omega$-limit set of a point $x \in X$ is correct:

$$\omega(x) = \{ y \in M : \exists \text{ sequence }\{t_j\}, \text{ where } t_j \rightarrow \infty, \text { such that } \varphi_{t_j} (x) \rightarrow y \text{ as } j \rightarrow \infty \}.$$

The context is ODEs, so $M$ is the phase space.

Comment: It is fine. You can also replace $t_j\to\infty$ by $t_j\nearrow \infty$.

Comment: @Jonas Would there be any benefit of this? It's not like $t_j$ can approach $\infty$ from above.

Comment: Indeed, understand it as "Sometimes people also replace".

Comment: Understood, thanks for the confirmation! Mind adding it as an answer?

Comment: Done. ---------

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a point $x \in M$, its $\omega$-limit set with respect to a flow $\varphi_t$ is defined by
$$
\omega(x)=\bigcap_{y \in \gamma(x)} \overline {\gamma^+(y)},
$$
where
$$
\gamma(x)=\big\{\varphi_t(x): t \in \mathbb R\big\}\quad\text{and}\quad\gamma^+(y)=\big\{\varphi_t(y): t >0\big\}.
$$
When $M$ is for example a smooth manifold (or simply $\mathbb R^n$), one can show that
$$
\omega(x)=\big\{y\in M:\text{there exists a sequence $t_k \to +\infty$ such that $\varphi_{t_k}(x) \to y$ when $k \to \infty$}\big\}.
$$